# How to use phing to build from manifest files

Tags: phing

I have an XML manifest that identifies units to be built, but each unit has important properties as tags, eg

```
<files>
    <file name="unit1" type="type1">filename1</file>
    <file name="unit2" type="type2">filename2</file>
    ...
</files>
```

I want to pass each "name"d unit to a build task according to "type".

Whilst I can use a foreach loop with something like list="${files.file.name}" after reading this XML file with xmlproperty, how do I get the other properties encapsulated in each "files.file" entry?

It looks like I should be able to access the "files" list as an array ("of arrays"?), but I can't find anything about how to access arrays in phing either.

(Using phing v3.0.0-RC4)